# Why does p4 print return strange line endings?

Tags: perforce

I need some help understanding why "p4 print" might return line endings other than what the system executing the command would expect.

I'm getting behavior when I print a specific file that leads me to believe that the Peforce server has non-unix style line endings stored.

Here is the behavior I'm expecting:

```
>p4 print -q //depot/path/to/file.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
>
```

Here is the behavior I'm seeing

```
>p4 print -q //depot/path/to/file.txt
>ine 4
```

I'm executing this on a linux machine.  p4 client is: 
Rev. P4/LINUX26X86/2013.2/707225 (2013/09/17)

Server is version 2013.2/740201

Can anybody help me understand what is stored incorrectly with this file on the server that is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging, we determined that the file was stored on the server with Old Mac style line endings (0x0D) rather than unix (0x0A) or windows style (0x0D0A)

After running "mac2unix" on the file, the line endings were fixed, and after submitting to Perforce all is resolved.